# Installing Tensor Flow docker image

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow

I am using the link below to install a tensor flow docker image and for the last step, when I run `sudo docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-jupyter`, I get this error message: **`Error response from daemon: manifest for tensorflow/tensorflow:devel-gpu-jupyter not found.`**

Please let me know if anyone has had similar issues. I am using a Google Cloud Platform with architecture: x86_64 and Ubuntu 16.04

Does anyone have simpler resources to install it?

Thank you for all your help!

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker

Comment: I have similar issues, I am guessing that there is issue with the jupyter tag AND latest tag images. Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on below link the tag is not available

https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/tags

You should use the latest gpu tag

```
docker pull tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu-py3
```

Comment: not sure if this is what is being asked here. I am looking for the image with jupyter notebooks as advertised on the webpage, which what the O is asking. If you have a solution that solves that problem,then I think it would be relevant.

Comment: @AtulKulkarni i think, this will resolve what you're looking for: "docker pull jupyter/tensorflow-notebook" https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/tensorflow-notebook